# Singular condition on an aggregate column

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

Slightly tough to define what I'm trying to get at, but taking a stab here. I'm working on redshift and writing a query on top of the following sample **Table A**:

```
User ID ||  Active_in_Month  || Max_Months_On_Platform
1           1                   6
1           2                   6
1           5                   6
2           1                   3
2           3                   3
```

After grouping by "Active_in_Month", I want to get at the following output in **Table B**:

```
Active_in_Month  ||   Active_Distinct_Users   ||   User_Cohorts
1                     2                            2
2                     1                            2
3                     1                            2
5                     1                            1
```

The "Active_Distinct_Users" is a simple COUNT(*). However, the calculation of "User_Cohorts" is where I'm stuck. The column is supposed to represent how many users were on the platform who have been active for at most the value in the "active_in_month" comlumn. For example, in Row 1 of **Table B**, there were two users who have "Max_Months_on_Platform" > 1 (Active in Month). In Row 5 of **Table B** there is only 1 "User_Cohort", because only 1 user has "Max Months on Platform" > 5 (Active_in_Month).

Hope this explains what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Solved it using the following way, not sure if its the best way but it got the job done:

```
SELECT
    Active_in_Month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id),
    ( SELECT 
SUM(number_of_customers)
          FROM (SELECT 
                  tbl_a2.Max_Months_On_Platform AS total,
                  COUNT(DISTINCT tbl_a2.user_id) AS number_of_customers
                FROM 
                  tbl_a AS tbl_a2
                GROUP BY tbl_a2.Max_Months_On_Platform
                )
            WHERE total + 1 >= tbl_a.Active_in_Month  
        ) AS total_customers

      FROM
        tbl_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i have understand the correct rule to calculate the value of User_Cohorts. try this please:

```
SELECT
    a.Active_in_Month
    , COUNT(*) AS Active_Distinct_Users
    , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) +1
        FROM tablea a2
        WHERE a.Active_in_Month < a2.Max_Months_On_Platform
        AND a.user_id <> a2.user_id
    ) AS User_Cohorts
FROM tablea a
GROUP BY a.Active_in_Month
ORDER BY a.Active_in_Month;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->     a.Active_in_Month
    ->     , COUNT(*) AS Active_Distinct_Users
    ->     , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) +1
    ->         FROM tablea a2
    ->         WHERE a.Active_in_Month < a2.Max_Months_On_Platform
    ->         AND a.user_id <> a2.user_id
    ->     ) AS User_Cohorts
    -> FROM tablea a
    -> GROUP BY a.Active_in_Month
    -> ORDER BY a.Active_in_Month;
+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+
| Active_in_Month | Active_Distinct_Users | User_Cohorts |
+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+
|               1 |                     2 |            2 |
|               2 |                     1 |            2 |
|               3 |                     1 |            2 |
|               5 |                     1 |            1 |
+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Thanks Bernd, but I'm getting an error saying that I need to group by a.user_id as well.

Comment: you can try **SET sql_mode='';** before

Comment: It may be because I was on redshift and not sql. I was finally able to solve it, though I don't think it's the most eloquent solution. Going to add the solution to the post. Thanks for your help!